# USB hub/specialized device that hides USB HID endpoints

Tags: usb, keyboards

I would like a USB device that would hide the existence of a subset of USB endpoints on a HID device, so that a computer only sees selected HID endpoints.

I've not been able to find a product explicitly described in this way.  What, if any, products are on the market that can do this (perhaps ones sold for other purposes: e.g. perhaps some USB hubs expose limited endpoints as a side-effect of their design?), and if so what terms are used to describe them?

To solve the problem, it should:

- Allows connecting HID devices in such a way that it never exposes more than 3 USB endpoints to the connected computer (in fact the "computer" role in my case is played by a KVM, see below), but passes through keyboard functionality, meeting my use case below
- Cost less than 500 dollars (more expensive products would certainly still be interesting to hear about, but won't fit my use)

Why I want this: I have a fast-switching DDM KVM which I use to "instantly" (imperceptibly fast) switch a USB keyboard and mouse between two computers.  The manufacturer tells me it doesn't support USB HID devices with more than 3 USB endpoints.  I have a keyboard with 4 USB endpoints.  At least one of the keyboard's endpoints is for mouse functionality (binding keys to mouse movements), which I don't use - in fact I suspect I only use a single endpoint, the one labelled "Keyboard".  I'd like to use that keyboard with the DDM KVM.